# Cant't send mail in hosting: Expected response code 250 but got code "550",

Tags: email, laravel-5, swiftmailer, shared-hosting

Recently i had deployed a laravel project to my sharedhosting and when i try to send a mail appears this error:

```
    (1/1) Swift_TransportException
     Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550-
     550-Hosting ACL: unauthorized IP (67.225.178.60). Mas informacion en
     550-https://hosting.cl/bloqueo-email.php
     550
```

In my local server it runs correctly using credentials of gmail:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=nameemail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

the credentials in my shared hosting looks something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=domain.com.pe
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@domain.com.pe
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Note: the email and passwords of shared hosting works perfectly in outlook.

Comment: you need to check the smtp settings of you email service provider.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many things to solve this error and nothing, so i contacted the support of my hosting provider and they could to solved.